# Standardizing Factor Loadings SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I have the following structural equation model with latent variables f1 and f2 and observed variables x1-x6:

```
Covariance Matrix:
      x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6
x1 1.100 0.440 0.532 0.089 0.168 0.029
x2 0.440 1.066 0.373 0.133 0.119 0.106
x3 0.532 0.373 1.027 0.066 0.144 0.130
x4 0.089 0.133 0.066 1.019 0.354 0.455
x5 0.168 0.119 0.144 0.354 1.022 0.420
x6 0.029 0.106 0.130 0.455 0.420 0.976
    Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  f1 =~                                                                 
    x1                1.000                               0.787    0.751
    x2                0.714    0.069   10.420    0.000    0.562    0.544
    x3                0.867    0.081   10.751    0.000    0.682    0.671
  f2 =~                                                                 
    x4                1.000                               0.629    0.624
    x5                0.933    0.088   10.554    0.000    0.587    0.581
    x6                1.133    0.110   10.267    0.000    0.713    0.722

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  f1 ~~                                                                 
    f2                0.097    0.027    3.528    0.000    0.196    0.196
 .x1 ~~                                                                 
   .x4                0.005    0.029    0.164    0.870    0.005    0.009
 .x2 ~~                                                                 
   .x5               -0.017    0.030   -0.549    0.583   -0.017   -0.023
 .x3 ~~                                                                 
   .x6                0.065    0.027    2.392    0.017    0.065    0.127

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .x1                0.480    0.058    8.213    0.000    0.480    0.437
   .x2                0.751    0.047   15.820    0.000    0.751    0.704
   .x3                0.568    0.049   11.514    0.000    0.568    0.550
   .x4                0.622    0.048   12.909    0.000    0.622    0.611
   .x5                0.677    0.047   14.436    0.000    0.677    0.663
   .x6                0.467    0.052    9.059    0.000    0.467    0.479
    f1                0.619    0.073    8.421    0.000    1.000    1.000
    f2                0.396    0.055    7.210    0.000    1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    x1                0.563
    x2                0.296
    x3                0.450
    x4                0.389
    x5                0.337
    x6                0.521
```

I'm trying to figure out how the standardized coefficients are calculated (std.all column). My initial thought from linear modeling was to divide by the ratio of the standard deviations, but this doesn't give the correct answers.

Edit: Based on comments I realized that f1s are my x's, and .x1-.x6 are actually y's, but this still doesn't yield the answer.

Comment: Latent variables are not ys, they are xs. The latent is the predictor, and they do have sds.

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying, but I'm still getting the wrong answers. So, for the standardized coefficient of x2 we should take coef(x2)/(sd(f1)/sd(x2)). That is: 0.714/(sqrt(0.619)/sqrt(0.751))=0.787. Which is what is appearing in the std.all column for x1, not x2. What really dumb mistake am I making?

Comment: `sqrt(.714 **2 * .619) / sqrt(.714 ** 2 * .619 + .751)` is how you get the .544 for x2, which is a little more complicated with the non-one loading. If I write that up, is it enough for the bounty? Or is there another value you'd like to see derived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's focus on $x_1$. When $f_1$'s coefficient is fixed to 1, the model is:

$$
x_1 = f_1 + \epsilon_1
$$
where $f_1 \sim N(0, .619)$ and $\epsilon_1 \sim N(0, .480)$.

Thus, $\text{Var}(x_1) = .619 + .480 = 1.099$ and $R^2 = .619 / 1.099 = .563$.

`Std.all` means that both the observed and latent variable variances are 1.0. Since we have flexibility with the latent variable, let's start by transforming the observed:

$$
x_1^* = x_1 / \sqrt{1.099} = (1 / \sqrt{1.099}) f_1 + (1 / \sqrt{1.099}) \epsilon_1.
$$

Now we have $\text{Var}(x_1^*) = 1$ and $\text{Var}(f_1) = .619$. We need the latent component's variance to be one as well, so we rewrite it as $f_1 = \sqrt{.619} * f_1 ^*$ and we arrive at

$$
x_1^* = \sqrt{.619 / 1.099} f_1^* + (1 / \sqrt{1.099}) \epsilon_1.
$$

$\sqrt{.619 / 1.099}$ is 0.75049, which *almost* rounds to .751. I think it's rounding error but you be the judge.