# Structure equation model how to compare observe variables contribution

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

[image]I have a model with one latent variable (two observed variables A and B). I think variable A is contributing to the majority of the entire model's significance, and variable B might contribute less or none. I wonder whether there is a way to compare statistically the contribution of observed variables A and B to this model. I am using the Lavaan package in R so any packages in R will be more useful. Also I tried SEM models with only A or B included, but it seems that variable A itself doesn't make the model significant (P= 0.1), and if only with variable B then P=0.8. My hypothesis is that variable A and B both will contribute the model but A's contribution is bigger. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks very much

Comment: Just curious, what is the path diagram on $A$, $B$ and the latent factor $L$?

Comment: I added my diagram @Galen

Comment: Is it not just the loadings of A and B?

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I think Lavaan has a command for plotting the path diagram from a string formula. [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/c465481dcf87a9f94d3be93df454f775) is a Python gist showing something similar.

Comment: Maybe [`lavaanPlot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/lavaanPlot.pdf).

Comment: @JeremyMiles I think it should be the loadings, but when I checked the output and it fixed the factor loading of the first indicator (A) to 1. So I didn't see where to find the loadings for A and B, and how to statistically compare the significant difference between the two loadings. Output looks similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518042/standardizing-factor-loadings-sem

Comment: The second loading is relative to the first. You could fix the second to 1.0 instead, and it won't have an effect.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Thanks. Is the "Estimate" in the output the loading? When variable A's loading (estimate) is 1, B's estimate is about 0.3, which is lower than 1. Does it mean Variable A contributes more to the model? Question 1: If so, is there a way to test whether the difference between two loadings is significant, or this comparison between 1 and 0.3 is good enough to report in a paper? Question 2 : When I fix B's loading as 1, then the estimate of A is about 3, which is still more than B's loading. But all the paths in the SEM are not significant anymore. How could I explain this?

Comment: A is 3x B, whichever way you do it. Things not being sig is weird. Can you post both models? (Maybe to the lavaan group - you might get more help there, as this is getting off topic for crossvalidated).